# проблема с нумерацией в пагинаторе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть проблемы при добавлении div.t-row  в пагинаторе неправильно формируется нумерация 
 [ссылка на рабочий код](https://plnkr.co/edit/m7X4vCyK2p3zg475zBE9?p=preview)

код:

```
$(".check-all").click(function () {
    $(".check-domen").not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
$(".domain_inp").change(function(){
    var inpDomain = $(this).val();

    $("#createD").bind("click", function () {
        $("#tba").append("<div class='t-row'><div class='col-1'>" +
                "<input class='check-domen checkbox' type='checkbox' name='check-domen'>" + "</div>" +
                "<div class='col-2'>" + "<div class='wrap-c2'>" + "<i class='site-ico'></i>" +
                "<a href='#' class='domen-name'>" + inpDomain + "</a></div></div></div>")

    var rowsTotal = $(".t-row").length;
    var rowsShown = 10;
    var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;

    for(i=0; i < numPages; i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        var pagLink = '<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+ pageNum +'</a>';
        /*$(this).closest(".wrap-table").append(pagLink)*/
        $(".wrap-paginator").append(pagLink);

    }
    $(".wrap-page #tba .t-row").hide();
    $(".wrap-page #tba .t-row").slice(0, rowsShown).show();


    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант замените ваш цикл

```
    $(".wrap-paginator").empty()
    for(i=0; i <= Math.floor(numPages); i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        var pagLink = '<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+ pageNum +'</a>';
        $(".wrap-paginator").append(pagLink);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в цикле:

```js
$(".wrap-paginator").append(pagLink);
```

На каждом проходе в .wrap-paginator добавляется ссылка, при этом старые ссылки остаются.

Можно изменить цикл следующим образом:

```js
var paginationHtml = '';
for (var i=0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    var pagLink = '<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+ pageNum +'</a>';
    paginationHtml += pagLink;
}
$(".wrap-paginator").html(paginationHtml);
```